# Use ZyXEL WAP 3205 as LAN to WLAN bridge

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bridge

I've got the following devices:

- ZyXEL WAP3205 WLAN Access Point [WAP]
- Comcast / Ubee device with 1 LAN port [COM]
- Laptop with LAN and WLAN [CLIENT]

I want to connect WAP to COM via the LAN port and access the internet from CLIENT via WLAN. 
Effectively using WAP as a WLAN -> LAN bridge

Complete Route: CLIENT -> WLAN -> WAP -> LAN -> COM -> Internet

Questions:

1. Is this possible at all?
2. How do I configure each device ?

What I tried so far:

1. switched WAP into "Access Point Mode", set IP address to DHCP, set up WLAN
2. connected WAP via LAN to COM
3. set CLIENT to DHCP, connected to WLAN
4. **CLIENT gets local (192.168.0.XXX) IP address, not able to access internet**

What works:

- connecting CLIENT via LAN to COM --> internet access
- connecting CLIENT to WAP via WLAN --> gets local IP address

Comment: Is your COM device doing NAT or is any client plugging into this device receiving a public IP address? What device is supposed to be doing NAT and providing DHCP in this case?

Comment: Currently not at home, so can't test. I would want to (and assume from reading the WAP manual) that COM provides DHCP/NAT and WAP just acts as a bridge

Answer (score 0):

**Based on your comments, the ideal setup you would want is as follows:**

1. COM is set up to provide DHCP and NAT. Assume for example sake that the public IP address is `79.79.79.79`. It's gateway address (interior of private network) is `192.168.0.1`.
2. WAP is configured to provide `DHCP Forwarding` and is pointed at `192.168.0.1`. Let's pretend you statically give WAP the IP address of `192.168.0.2` in the `DHCP Reservation Table` of COM.
3. You will want to bridge the wireless and the LAN port of WAP. Or, if need be, set a default route to COM to forward all traffic that way.

**How it works:**
Your client will use DHCP to request an IP address. It forwards this to its default router which is your WAP. Your WAP will forward it along to COM and it will reply back with all the necessary information. It should have network connectivity from this point on. The ideal situation is where the WAP only acts as a layer 2 device and simply forwards all packets along to the COM and lets it deal with it. But I don't know if the device is capable of that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of how that works in general. I just want to know how to setup the WAP to make it work.